# Migration issue from sandbox to dev org during package creation

Tags: managed-package, deployment, ant, package

I am planning to create a managed package. Since managed packages cant be created in sandboxes , I created one dev org and tried to move the Profiles and Objects from my sand box to Dev org. But I am always getting below error.

```
18.  objects/Case.object (Case.Language) -- Error: Could not resolve standard field's name. (line 1292, column 13)
19.  profiles/Caseworker.profile -- Error: Unknown user permission: OverrideForecasts
20.  profiles/Intake Worker.profile -- Error: Unknown user permission: AIViewInsightObjects
21.  profiles/Provider Community.profile -- Error: Unknown user permission: OverrideForecasts
22.  profiles/Public Community.profile -- Error: Unknown user permission: OverrideForecasts
23.  profiles/Supervisor.profile -- Error: Unknown user permission: ApproveContract
```

Can you please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dev Org you're using doesn't have some of the features found in your Sandbox, so the permissions presented are causing deployment errors. You need to manually remove those from your .profile files, or enable those features in your new Dev Org. For new Managed Packages, I recommend [Second-Generation Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp.htm). This lets you create Scratch Orgs instead of Dev Orgs, which let you specify features you want in the org without Support's help, and should also be easier to maintain long-term.

Comment: I am following the way to create 2GP managed package. So i created one scratch org from my PROD. Even after that also i am getting "Case.Language: Could not resolve standard field's name".

Comment: @SFDC-Beginner You need to enable translation workbench to use this field.